# Bad URL Error With NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, url, nsurlrequest

I have a NSURLRequest created next way:

```
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserveradress.com/api/users/register?register_password=%@&register_password_confirm=%@&register_email=%@&register_terms=1&register_user=%@&process_registration=1&register_name=%@"
                   ,
                   [password stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"],[confirm stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"],[email stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"],[user stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"],[realName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%"]
                   ];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    NSString *result_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result_string;
```

The result string is `http://myserveradress.ru/api/users/register?register_password=password&register_password_confirm=password&register_email=myname@mail.com&register_terms=1&register_user=myname&process_registration=1&register_name=Artem%Kulikov` and the error states

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x71e62b0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x71e6470 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

In browser the link works fine. The problem is only in the app.

Comment: Have you tried typing it into a browser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is not the proper way to escape the strings, there is a method for that, `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. So change it to:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserveradress.com/api/users/register?register_password=%@&register_password_confirm=%@&register_email=%@&register_terms=1&register_user=%@&process_registration=1&register_name=%@"
                   , password, confirm, email, user, realName];
NSString *properlyEscapedURL = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:properlyEscapedURL]];
```

Not to mention the proper escape code for a space is `%20` not `%`.

Comment: Superb man.. +1 for answer. Stuck with french characters in url request.

Answer (score 2):

@user1506704, you are not use encoding method like in register_name,  Are there spaces or other special characters in the register_name? Use `NSString` method   `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:.`

You can try and escape the URL:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`
```